# What is so special about $0.368$ (the $x$ that minimizes $x^x$ and other functions)?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

Hello math stack exchange,

I was playing around with the Desmos graphing calculator the other day and found out that when you put in $x^x$, the absolute minimum of the graph is located at $x=0.368$. When I put in $\ln(x) * x$, it also came up with the absolute minimum where $x=0.368$. Really, any number times $x^x$ or $x(\ln x)$ comes up with the absolute minimum where $x=0.368$.

> Is there something special about that number? Are there any other functions that have this special relationship with $0.368$, and how does $x^x$ relate to the natural log of a number?

Thank you

Edit: Thank you everyone for the answers. It makes sense now since $\ln(0.368)=-1$. Hope everyone has a good day.

Comment: It's $\frac 1e$.

Comment: $\ln(x^x)=x\ln x,$ so $x^x$ and $x\ln x$ will be minimized at the same $x,$ if there is a minimum for either one.

Comment: In general, if $f(x)$ has a minimum at $x=x_0$ and $g(x)$ is a strictly increasing function, then $g(f(x))$ has a minimum at $x=x_0.$ So $g(x)=ax,$ for $a>0$ works, as does $g(x)=e^x.$

Answer (score 3):

The derivative of $x^x$ is $xx^{x-1} + x^x\ln(x)$, set it to $0$, we get $x+x\ln(x)=0$, $\ln(x)=-1, x=e^{-1}=0.3678...$ is the only critical point of the function over $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: Note $xx^{x-1} + x^x\ln(x) = x^x ( 1 + \ln(x))$